# Should I disconnect() if I'm using Apache::DBI's connect_cached()?

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, dbi, apache2.2, mod-perl2

My mod_perl2-based intranet app uses `DBI->connect_cached()` which is supposedly overridden by `Apache::DBI`'s version of the same.  It has normally worked quite well, but just recently we started having an issue on our testing server--which had only two users connected--whereby our app would sometimes, but not always, die when trying to reload a page with 'FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already' connecting to our postgres 9.0 backend, despite all of them being `<IDLE>` if I look at the stats in pgadmin3.

The backend is separate from our development and production backends, but they're all configured with `max_connections = 100`.  Likewise the httpd services are all separate, but configured with

```
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      99
MaxClients       99
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
....
PerlModule Apache::DBI
```

I had been under the impression that I shouldn't call `disconnect()` on my database handles if I wanted them to actually benefit from caching.  Was I wrong about that?  If not, I guess I'll ask about the above error separately.  Just wanted to make sure it wasn't this setup...

[Apache::DBI's docs](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Apache-DBI/lib/Apache/DBI.pm) say:

> When loading the DBI module (do not confuse this with the Apache::DBI
>   module) it checks if the environment variable 'MOD_PERL' has been set
>   and if the module Apache::DBI has been loaded. In this case every
>   connect request will be forwarded to the Apache::DBI module.
>   ....
>   There is no need to remove the disconnect statements from your code.
>   They won't do anything because the Apache::DBI module overloads the
>   disconnect method.
>
> If you are developing new code that is strictly for use in mod_perl,
>   you may choose to use DBI->connect_cached() instead, but consider
>   adding an automatic rollback after each request, as described above.

So I guess for my mod_perl2-only app, I don't need Apache::DBI because Apache::DBI's devs recommend using DBI->connect_cached.  And I don't need disconnect statements.

But then [DBI's docs](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.630/DBI.pm) say:

> Note that the behaviour of [ connect_cached ] differs in several
>   respects from the behaviour of persistent connections implemented by
>   Apache::DBI. However, if Apache::DBI is loaded then connect_cached
>   will use it.

This makes it sound like Apache::DBI will actually affect connect_cached, in that instead of getting DBI->connect_cached behaviour when I call that, I'll get Apache::DBI->connect behaviour.  And Apache::DBI's docs recommend against that.

UPDATE: I've set the first 5 parameters in the above config all to 1, and my app is still using up more and more connections as I hit its pages.  This I don't understand at all--it should only have one process, and that one process should be re-using its connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you plan on dropping Apache::DBI, the answer is a firm no, because [Apache::DBI's override](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PHRED/Apache-DBI-1.12/lib/Apache/DBI.pm) really does nothing:

```
# overload disconnect
{
  package Apache::DBI::db;
  no strict;
  @ISA=qw(DBI::db);
  use strict;
  sub disconnect {
      my $prefix = "$$ Apache::DBI            ";
      Apache::DBI::debug(2, "$prefix disconnect (overloaded)");
      1;
  }
  ;
}
```