# Are "best practices" regarding connection handle re-use and database user design mutually exclusive?

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, database

SO says this may be subjective.  I'm hoping not--I just can't seem to understand how this works in practice, and it seems like a specific enough technical question with I hope a definitive answer.

**Context:** LAPP stack.

1. I've read that using a single database user as the login for all connections to the database, and handling security yourself from there, is a bad idea.  Databases have sufficient security models and it makes sense to use them.
2. Database handles have some resource cost associated with them, hence the existence of Apache::DBI, DBIx::Connector, and DBI::connect_cached(), to re-use a recent connection to a database.  Making use of them should make a web app faster by avoiding the cost of connecting to a database.

The reason these seem to be mutually exclusive best practices is that, in my understanding, #1 implies that any database connection will be made with separate per-user credentials, which implies (as [Apache::DBI documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475956/should-i-disconnect-if-im-using-apachedbis-connect-cached)) that re-using such connections will likely quickly cause your database backend to run out of connections.

The default maximum number of connections for PostgreSQL is 100.

The default numbers of servers and multiplied by subprocesses allowed for each, for Apache 2 running with the prefork MPM, far exceeds that, so it seems Apache::DBI's docs are right.

**Thus the question**: What do people do then, in practice?

Does this mean people using a LAPP stack generally connect using a single database user, and implement their own security/permissions model?  Or does it mean they don't pool connections?  Or do they choose between these two strategies based on speed vs security needs if they go with a LAPP stack, and if they need both, go with a desktop app or some other connection model?

Or if these are not, in fact, mutually exclusive strategies, what am I missing in my understanding here?

Comment: I think you are getting application ID's and user ID's confused. For example a Application might have other security restrictions that cannot be modelled on the database. I would create a application ID that I can enforce SQL related permissions on and also use in my custom scheme if needs be. I would then create user id for users that needs to access the database directly such as ETL, Admin and other workers. Having a single application ID does make auditing easier and ensures that the right permissions are used. Using one super id IS a bad idea.

Comment: Sounds probable.  So a "database user" is actually an application, and an actual real-life user using my application should not be a "database user", even if I only have one application?  If so, that's unfortunate: I was finding it very convenient to have users' and groups' permissions built into tables, views, and functions.  It had seemed natural.

Comment: @Kev: it seems natural until you need to need to manage an unusual scenario, e.g.: grant this person access to my stuff on the 1st of each month if this condition is fulfilled.

Comment: @Denis, the view approach with postgres handles that scenario OK too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've read that using a single database user as the login for all connections to the database, and handling security yourself from there, is a bad idea. Databases have sufficient security models and it makes sense to use them.

You probably misread this, or read it in a highly biased location. A more balanced view is (hopefully) this:

- Managing perms (ACL or RBAC or other) within the database is a bloody mess and hard to get right. It can cripple performance, too, if done improperly (think: "select * from table join perms where convoluted_permission_scenario".) Depending on who you ask, you'll get more or less extreme viewpoints, e.g. here's (the very controversial) Zed Shaw: http://vimeo.com/2723800.
- Managing perms at the DB level is just as much of a bloody mess. Not all engines implement row-level permissions, and even then there occasionally are leaks. For instance, calling a function in a where clause could (can?) leak rows in Postgres (until a recent version?) if `raise` gets called. And frankly, if you go past a superficial analysis of what is going on, it basically amounts to the former — just standardized and (usually) in C.
- Managing perms at the app level *without* a database is *also* a bloody mess. It'll cripple performance no matter what you do from the moment where you need to join outside of SQL, unless you're dealing with trivial amounts of data. If you try it, you'll do fine… until your database grows too large and you basically don't.

So, in short: it's a bloody mess no matter where you manage it. Because permissions *are* a mess. In addition to the casual and idealistic "Joe needs write access to this set of nodes", you also need to cope with more down to earth scenarios such as "John is going off on vacation for Christmas and needs to temporarily delegate his write permissions on this set of nodes to his assistant Jane". Moreover, whichever scenario you do pick, you *need* to manage read access (which is usually the most frequent) in such a way that it's fast so you can scale. There's no silver bullet.

Moreover, even in the first and last of the above scenarios, it's ideal to have three DB users. One for reads, one for read/writes, and one for schema changes. Most apps don't, because it's yet another bloody mess to configure your ORM that way, hence the typical one DB user per app.

Anyway, getting back to your question: what people do in practice is one or two database users (read vs read/write/modify), implement RBAC or ACL within the database itself, and avoid access restriction logic like the plague on public-facing pages for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks, that's informative.  I've worked around row-level permissions using views with simple where clauses--most tables have a "my_tablename" view that only shows rows created by the user (created_by_column = current_user::text::integer).  I guess such an approach, which I thought was clever at the time, is not meant to be used in LAPP land.

Comment: That scenario is clever but it wouldn't get you very far in a sales application where each of payee, deliveree, sales staff, sales managers, support staff, support managers, senior execs and occasionally their secretaries, as well as their cats, dogs, ponies and unicorns, you name it, need a potentially separate set of permissions on a particular node.

Comment: Denis described a public-facing web scenario accurately. Databases that have relatively little web access--possibly only to remote offices of the same company--usually use more database-level permissions and fewer application-level permissions.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall', that's an important distinction.  This is for an intranet app, but even with the relatively low numbers involved we've run out of database connections, which is what brought up this design consideration for me.

Comment: @Denis, I suppose not.  Although, I seem to recall a certain project using Postgres that promised row-level permissions in a relatively sane setup.  I'm sure there would be gotchas there too, though.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy BTW Postgres now has row-level permissions built-in.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html